# How to use guacenc in guacamole?

Tags: guacamole

I am running guacamole using docker image. I want to record RDP session. I've recorded RDP session, which is in raw format. In guacamole doc there is a utility called **guacenc** which convert recorded file data into a .m4v video format by using this command.

**guacenc /path/to/recording/NAME.**

Here I do not know, where I've to run this command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged into a terminal session on your server.